# gcp functions fails to connect to the grpc protocol through the vpn to the grpc port of the aws eks container

Tags: google-cloud-functions, network-programming, amazon-eks, grpc-java, aws-vpn

The gcp function (nodejs environment) is the eks cluster java container connected to aws through vpn, the protocol uses grpc, and the connection times out

Java application error log:
HTTP/2 client preface string missing or corrupt. Hex dump for received bytes

Test status

1. Functions tcp connection can be successful through vpn or public network
2. Functions grpc connection through vpn does not work, and grpc can connect successfully through the public network
3. It is possible to connect the gcp server tcp or grpc through vpn or public network

I have ruled out the problems below the TCP transport layer. Tools such as ping traceroute telnet can be connected, and the firewall also allows all 0.0.0.0/0 routing tables to be fine.

I think the problem should be located in the application layer GRPC of Function, because I also wrote a test case running on the GCP server and connecting to GRPC can be successful

But I don't know how to check further

Any geeks have any ideas?